# How to get whole dimensions of a scrollview to know how much I have to scroll

Tags: android, width, scrollview, measurement

I'm trying to determine wether or not I have to scroll (and how much) my tabs to show others if they are uncomplete. To achieve so I need to know how much my TabHost (inside a HorizontalScrollView) is out of the screen (in pixels).

Untill now i've tried

```
        int totalLength = 0, totalLength1 = 0;
        for(int i =0; i<mTabHost.getChildCount(); i++){
            try {
                totalLength += mTabHost.getChildAt(i).getWidth();
                totalLength1+= mTabHost.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                toast("ERROR: "+i);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But it returns as much as the screen width, not a single pixel more.
`mScrollView.getWidth()` also returns my screen width when exceeds it.
`mScrollView.getMeasureWidth()` doesn't work either.

I've done some research but so far all that I've found is something called `mScrollview.getMaxSCrollAmmout()`; but I had a bad time trying to figure out how it works

**EDIT:** `mScrollview.getMaxSCrollAmmout()` didn't work either.

**EDIT 2:** It seems like the action is pretty similar to what ViewPagerIndicator does, if someone is familiar with the source code may can splain to me :D